# css dropdown menu keeps expanding main

Tags: css, list, menu

i just made my first css drop down menu and i am very proud of it , but i have a problem, when the submenu is expanding, it pulls down the main ul , and i dont want that .. it must stay the  height i have given it .. so the purple div below stays in same place even if the submenu expands .. thank you

Here is jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/v937B/71/

here is my code

```
<ul  class="menu">      
    <li>
        <a href="#">Forside</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Nyheder</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">Galleri</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">Andet</a>
    </li>     
    <li>Vores hunde
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Hvalpe</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Hanner</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tæver</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<div style="float:left; width:100%; background:#FF00FF;">&nbsp;</div>
```

and here is my css

```
ul.menu{
text-align:center;
display: table; 
width: 100%;
height:48px;
line-height:48px;
border: 1px solid red;   
}

ul.menu li {
background:yellow;
display: table-cell; 
border: 0px solid yellow;   
}

ul.menu li a { 
display:block; 
background:blue;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
display:block; 
background:purple;
}

.submenu {
display: none;
}

.menu li:hover .submenu {
display: block;
}

ul.submenu {
text-align:center;
}

ul.submenu  li {
display:block;
text-align:center;
background:green; 
border:0px;
}

ul.submenu li a { 
color:red; 
text-align:center; 
background:pink;
}

ul.submenu li a:hover {
color:red; 
text-align:center; 
background:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

`position: absolute;` to your `.submenu` class

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lotus/v937B/73/)

Comment: Thank you so much .. this is why i love stackoverflow, always so helpful people :)

Comment: how do i make the submenu stretch to same width as the li that expands it? i tried adding width:100% but it makes it stretch to fill out the page..